# When is the trace $\sigma$-algebra used?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am starting a course on measure theory in relation to probability and martingales.

I just proved that if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space and $E\subseteq\Omega$ then $\{E\cap A:A\in\mathcal{F}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$. (Note: strictly, $E$ should be non-empty.)

Apparently this is called the *trace* $\sigma$-*algebra*. As I haven't gotten far yet, I am wondering where this might be used later on. Any information as to its significance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'll tell you one: What we have if $ E:= [0;1]?

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński So $E$ is the closed unit interval $[0,1]$. What is the set and sigma algebra? I'm still not sure where this goes sorry

Comment: This concern probability matter

Comment: The prime example that comes to my mind is the $\sigma$-algebra on which [Wiener measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4368983/949989) lives when $\Omega$ is the set of all continuous functions. My advice however is that you should progress steadily and not jump to advanced topics too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example is the useful fact that $\mathcal{B}([0, 1])$ equals the trace of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ on $[0, 1]$, allowing you to use Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. Another example is for transferring results on measure spaces from the finite case to the $\sigma$-finite case. Having a natural $\sigma$-algebra on all measurable subsets of the space is very useful for this purpose.